# Laravel custom Request validation always gives validation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to use make a put request using custom request validation. Here is my code:

#### api.php

```
Route::put('/update-pdf-resource/{resource}', 'ManagementController@updatePdfResource');
```

#### ManagementController.php

```
public function updatePdfResource(Resources $resource, UpdatePdfResourceRequest $request)
{

   $resource->type = $request->type;
   $resource->title = $request->title;
   $resource->file = $request->file('file')->store('files', 'public')l
   $resource->save();
   return response(['message' => 'Resource updated successfully'], 201);
}
```

#### UpdatePdfResourceRequest.php

```
public function rules()
{
   return [
      'type' => 'required',
      'title' => 'required',
      'file' => 'required | mimes:pdf'
   ];
 }
```

Now whenever I try to update a entry it sends me following error
[image]

The Request header is

[image]

It's hitting the correct route with correct data, but throwing validation error. How to solve it ?

#### Correction:

I just returned the $request beginning of the `updatePdfResource` method & it returns an empty array ! but in header it's showing the proper payload as above !

Comment: echo your form field data and check is it empty or not

Comment: please see the edited question

Comment: Are you sure you are sending your data in a proper format? If you're using JSON, you need the json header, if you're using multipart, add the multipart header.

Answer (score 0):

Requests should always come first

change it

```
public function updatePdfResource(Resources $resource, UpdatePdfResourceRequest $request)
```

to this

```
public function updatePdfResource(UpdatePdfResourceRequest $request, Resources $resource)
```

and you have a syntax error in your code "l" instead of ";"

```
->store('files', 'public')l
```

Comment: Corrected. But not working. Please see the edited question